# UPGRADE to PHP7: MPDF Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, mpdf

I know this is old question, but I hope by this post can help other when MPDF6 in PHP7.

Recently, I've just upgrade my system to PHP7.0 then I found `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in path/to/app/lib/MPDF60/mpdf.php:25051`. It's work fine while use PHP5.

**Error in this part:**

```
$this->divwidth = $cw-$extraWLR;
```

On the top of page was initialited with:

```
var $divwidth;
```

`print_r` of `$cw` is :

```
Array
(
    [miw] => 0
    [maw] => 0
)
```

`print_r` of `$extraWLR` is :
 `0.77611111111112`

How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mPDF 6 is not entirely compatible with PHP 7. [Upgrade to mPDF 7](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html#upgrading-from-older-mpdf-versions), which is tested up to PHP 7.2.